# Why is "who mil" allowed to produce no output?

Tags: history, posix, who

In the 2016 edition of IEEE Std 1003.1-2008 (a.k.a. The Open Group Base Specifications Issue 7, or just the POSIX standard), [the Rationale section of the `who` utility](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/who.html#tag_20_156_18) mentions the following:

> It is acceptable for an implementation to produce no output for an invocation of *who* **mil**.

Who or what is "mil"? Why is an implementation allowed to produce no output for `who mil`?

Comment: That's military.

Comment: Mother in law? ;-)

Comment: It would make sense if it read `who -ml`.

Comment: Perhaps "mil" is a placeholder for any word. My `who` produces no output for `who mil`, `who unix SE`, `who GnP` and anything else I threw at it. Not even `who am i` made it tick. GNU Coreutils 8.25-2ubuntu2.

Answer (score 1):

Reading the man page of "who", it says the first positional argument represents the file which is to be read.  Adding the argument "mil" tells "who" to open "./mil" and inspect it for login information...since there (presumably) is no such file, it outputs nothing...as if there were no users logged in.  I suppose it **could** output some useful error messages, but that may be counterproductive.  E.g., imagine the case where the system has just started, and no users have yet signed in.  In that case, the login file would be empty or non-existent.  Thus, the proper output from "who" is "no response" (i.e. no users are signed in) instead of a misleading error message.

Comment: It crossed my mind, but I don't think this is the answer per se. First, file arguments are an XSI extension, and I'm not sure if this feature was included in early versions of `who` (I'd have to disassemble [UNIX v1's utilities to see](https://github.com/jserv/unix-v1/tree/master/fs/root/bin). Furthermore, as the other XSI extension `who am i` breaks this pattern, I wouldn't be so quick  expect `who mil` to read a file; it might just be a similar easter egg.

Comment: Who accepted a file argument as early as [V3](http://www.tuhs.org/cgi-bin/utree.pl?file=V3/man/man1/who.1). I think the posix standard just has a typo and they meant to say "who file".